# How can I create a setter for a UIScrollView generated from the storyboard using Swift?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, xcode6

Using interface builder, I dragged out a UIScrollView onto my ImageViewController.

I control-dragged from the ScrollView onto my ImageViewController to get an IBOutlet to control the scrollView. Which added the code:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView
```

Now I want to set a property on the scrollView right after it is initialized.

In objective C you would write this function to achieve it:

```
-(void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  _scrollView = scrollView
  self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image ? self.image.size : CGSizeZero;
}
```

This would set the contentSize on the scroll view right after it has been initialized.

Currently in Swift I am achieving similar functionality by wrapping the self.scrollView inside a new var with a get function like so:

```
var sgScrollView: UIScrollView
{
    get {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image!.size
        return self.scrollView!
    }
}
```

Then instead of using this code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.imageView)
```

I use this:

```
self.sgScrollView.addSubview(self.imageView)
```

Which sets the content size upon getting the scrollView.

But in the objective C tutorial I am following they set the content size of the scrollView right after it has been initialized and set, like the obj-c function above. How can I do that using Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a great place to use Swift's *property observers*. You can define `willSet` and `didSet` observers on any property in your class. You'd want a `didSet` observer for this:

```
class ImageViewController : ViewController {
    var image : UIImage?
    @IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView {
    didSet {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image?.size ?? CGSizeZero
    }
    }

    ...
}
```